# angular4 unit test for window.location.href redirect to external link not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My logout button when clicked should take to an external link out of the application. it is working as expected but unit test case not working because we can not mock window.location.href. So I used two functions to call window.location.href indirectly, but still not working, can someone help me on this. component.ts is as follows:

```
doRedirect(hreflink) {
    window.location.href = hreflink;
  }
  logOut() {
    const hrefUrl = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
    if ((window.location.origin.indexOf('dev') > -1) ) {
      this.doRedirect('https://test.xxx.com/autho/logout.html?redirectTo=' + hrefUrl);

    }else {
      this.doRedirect('https://prod.xxx.com/autho/logout.html?redirectTo=' + hrefUrl);

}
```

Unit test case spec.ts is as follows:-

```
it('should call logout method if user clicks on logout link', fakeAsync(() => {
    const comp = TestBed.get(AppComponent);
    spyOn(comp, 'logOut').and.callFake(function(){});
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const elem = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.logout');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    elem.click();
    expect(comp.logOut).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand from your code is that you are testing onclick behaviour of the button. You are only testing if user clicks on the button, logout method shoul be called. You don't need to test onclick event of a button. You only need to test your code. Please let me know if your intention to write the test was something else.

However if you want to make your test work you can change it to this:

```
it('should call logout method if user clicks on logout link', fakeAsync(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  spyOn(app, 'logOut');
  const elem = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.logout');
  elem.click();
  expect(app.logOut).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

}));

However as I said before there is no need to write this test. One thing that you might test is checking if user will be redirected to the correct page by looking at the origin. That would be a better test to write.

By the way I don't think you need to wrap everything in fakeAsync as you are not testing anything asynchronously.

UPDATE:
If you want to test the functionality you can put it in a method that is going to return the desired navigation string. Then you can simply test that.

In your component:

```
 getRedirectString = ((origin: string, hrefUrl: string):string => 
    (origin.indexOf('dev') > -1 ? 
      'https://test.xxx.com/autho/logout.html?redirectTo=':
      'https://prod.xxx.com/autho/logout.html?redirectTo='
    ) + hrefUrl);
```

And then in your tests:

```
it('when use is in dev, getRedirectString should return the expected navigation string', () => {
    expect(this.app.getRedirectString("xxdevxx")).toContain('test');
  })
  it('when use is in not dev, getRedirectString should return the expected navigation string', () => {
    expect(this.app.getRedirectString("xxxx")).toContain('prod');
  })
```

Comment: Thank You @Bahman, I wanted to write test case for logout function. I am new to Angular so struggling. This is perfectly working fine.

Comment: @C. T. Can you please approve the answer if it was helpful?

Comment: @Bhaman, Thank you for your update. As per that, I can check for URL to have some string but issue is I am checking window.location.origin to confirm if it has 'dev' or 'prod' and based on that I am adding redirect url. Your code is good and will work fine for other cases though. Thank you again.

Comment: So you only need to change your code amd pass window.location.origin to getRedirectString method. In this way you will isolate your logic and don't need to mock window.location.origin. Does it make sense?

Comment: Can you please approve the answer if it was helpful?